# How to disable default sound effects for all my application or activity

Tags: android

In my application I am using sound pool for the button click audio effect.
The problem is that if in the device's settings "Audible selection" is ticked, then my buttons will produce two sounds: the system one and my one at the same time.

It seems that if in each button properties I set "Sound Effects Enabled" to false, the system sound is not heard any more. But I have many buttons across a dozen of activities, plus I am adding a matrix of buttons in code, so it is rather inconvenient to set "Sound Effects Enabled" to false manually for each one of them. Not sure how I do this in code..

Is there a more global way to stop "Audible selection" in my application or at least for the one activity?

Comment: Your accepted ans in not working for me. I'm doing the  same thing. Help!!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Create a theme file "res/values/styles.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

And then reference to it in your "AndroidManifest.xml"

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score 30):

I just had the same problem for my application. I was able to turn off sound feedback globally by putting `android:soundEffectsEnabled=false` in a theme.

Comment: Perhaps that is the answer I was looking for. This would work for only one activity, right? I would have then to assign the theme to every activity... Though I don't think every device behaves the same way, I have experienced that some devices turne off the sound globally on the first instance of a button whith android:soundEffectsEnabled=false but not all.

Comment: You can apply the theme to the entire application from the manifest file.

Answer (score 11):

You could create your own Button class and use that in the XML layout files...

```
package com.mycompany.myApp

public class MyButton extends Button {

    public MyButton (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Then in the XML layout files use...

```
<com.mycompany.myApp.MyButton
    ...
</com.mycompany.myApp.MyButton>
```

...for your Buttons.

Comment: Thank you for a good example. That is a lot of changes I have 17 layouts... wish if it was an easier way.

Comment: then why not put   'android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"' in xml view instead creating custom button

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom view that extends from Button. Then just set the Sound Effect Enabled to false on its creation.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

You can also go further and make the view know which new custom sound should be played.

Comment: My application is almost finished, I would have to change all my layouts and code for each of a dozen of activities to do this.

Comment: You can't just do a simple string replace in all your layout XML files to switch to the custom button?!