# How to enable haptic on default keybord button's click?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-audiomanager

I am developing a small app and I open system default keyboard but when I press keys only key-tap sound played. I want enable vibration also when click on any keys of keyboard.
Please help me how it is performed through programming.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that that this not easily acomplished,
see this SO post for an explanation:
[enable/disable keyboard sound and vibration programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395601/enable-disable-keyboard-sound-and-vibration-programmatically)