# Vibration on keypress in android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am creating a custom keyboard for android. On keypress of my keyboard, what I want is vibration on it's touch like android soft keyboard. I even referred to this answer [enable/disable keyboard sound and vibration programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395601/enable-disable-keyboard-sound-and-vibration-programmatically) but I couldn't understand how to use it. Can anyone explain how to get this feature in my custom keyboard app?

Answer (score 0):

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

Don't forget to include vibration in your Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this if you have root access. Its a lengthy process but you can do this :

Step : 1 
Create xml file named `com.android.inputmethod.latin_preferences.xml` and save in assets.

`com.android.inputmethod.latin_preferences.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <boolean name="popup_on" value="false" />
    <string name="auto_correction_threshold">1</string>
    <boolean name="pref_enable_metrics_logging" value="true" />
    <boolean name="pref_voice_input_key" value="true" />
    <boolean name="pref_key_use_personalized_dicts" value="true" />
    <boolean name="pref_key_block_potentially_offensive" value="true" />
    <int name="last_shown_emoji_category_id" value="1" />
    <boolean name="sound_on" value="false" />
    <string name="emoji_recent_keys">[{&quot;Integer&quot;:128533}]</string>
    <boolean name="auto_cap" value="true" />
    <boolean name="show_suggestions" value="true" />
    <boolean name="pref_key_use_contacts_dict" value="true" />
    <boolean name="next_word_prediction" value="true" />
    <boolean name="pref_key_use_double_space_period" value="true" />
    <int name="emoji_category_last_typed_id1" value="0" />
    <boolean name="vibrate_on" value="true" />
</map>
```

Step 2 : Copy this file into your application folder (anywhere where you can access) using `asset manager` for that you need

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

this function will copy file from assets

```
public static void copyAssets(Context context, String assetPath, String outFilename) {
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            in = assetManager.open(assetPath);
            File outFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), outFilename);

            out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            copyFile(in, out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to copy asset: " + outFilename, e);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
```

Step 3 : overwrite the system preference file system path (destPath) is `/data/data/com.android.inputmethod.latin/shared_prefs`

```
public static void copyToSystem(final String sourceFilePath, final String destPath) {
        Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
//                    
                    os.writeBytes("cp -f " + sourceFilePath + " " + destPath + "\n");
                    os.flush();
                    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                    os.flush();
                    process.waitFor();
                    process.waitFor();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
        background.start();
    }
```

Step 4 : Reboot device

That's all done. These step will disable key press sound and enable key press vibration of the device.