# How to refresh system preference changed programmatically?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am working to disable sound of key press and even I succeed in that. Actually for disable sound of key press I replace system preference file with my changed file but it doesn't effect until I restart device. So I want to know can we refresh system preference value.

You can check my code [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395601/enable-disable-keyboard-sound-and-vibration-programmatically/16559531#answer-47076972)

Comment: show your codes

Comment: You can check my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395601/enable-disable-keyboard-sound-and-vibration-programmatically/16559531#answer-47076972 on this link