# Programatically prevent default button sound on Android

Tags: android, button, audio, default

In an Android app designed for Froyo, I have a button that plays a music file when you tap it. However it also plays the default "button click" sound, which covers the start of the music. How can I prevent the "click" sound from being played automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for removing the click sound:

```
buttonName.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Fareya! When I use "disable" in my search (rather than "prevent" or "stop") I find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5023170/1927589), with answers on how to disable the sound effects for all buttons in a theme.